# Checking if a polynomial is in the ideal of Q[x]

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

In the ring of polynomials $Q[x]$, let $p(x)$ = $x+3$ and let J be the ideal generated by $p(x)$.

Does $x^3$ + $2x$ + $6$ $∈$ $J$ ?

So my simple approach was to actually try the definition but I still can't seem to "visualize" it. Any hint or help so I can do the rest of the exercises that involve the ideals of polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^3+2x+6=x^3+x+3+x+3 \implies \tilde{f}(x)=\tilde{x^3} \neq 0 \in \mathbb Q[x]/(p),$

where the last inequality comes from the fact that $x^3$ does not contain $x+3$ as a factor.

However, $f$ should take the value $0$ in the quotient, if it belonged to $J$. This is just rephrasing the fact that $p$ does not divide $f$.

Comment: This means, that for it to be in the ideal I just have to check if p(x) divides f(x)? When you talk about k[x], you're talking about...?

Comment: Yes. If you consider the ideal generated by a single element $(a)$, this means that all elements of it are multiples of $a$, (polynomials in $a$ with no constant term.) $k[x]$ was edited, before it was an arbitrary field.

Comment: Thank you very much, Andres, this has been an enlightenment for the next exercises.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(x)=x^3+2x+6$ . Does $f(-3)=0\,$?

Comment: This is a nice and simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

For each $f\in{\mathbb Q}[x]$, $f\in J$ iff the division of $f$ by $p$ has remainder $r=0$.